# Conditional Statement is always True

Tags: c#, if-statement, asp.net-mvc-5, conditional-statements

The following *if* statement(s) should only execute if a property of the object that is being binded matches a record that is already in the database:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,AID,Date,PostPreID")] OL oLevel)
{

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(oLevel.PostPreID == 2)
            {
                if (db.OL.Any(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(oLevel.Date) && x.PostPreID == oLevel.PostPreID))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("PostPreID", "There is already a record for this Date!");
                        return View(oLevel);
                    }
                else
                {
                    db.OL.Add(oLevel);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = oLevel.AID });
                }
            }

            if(oLevel.PostPreID == 3)
            {
                if (db.OL.Any(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(oLevel.Date) && x.PostPreID == oLevel.PostPreID))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("PostPreID", "There is already a record for this Date!");
                    return View(oLevel);
                }
                else
                {
                    db.OL.Add(oLevel);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = oLevel.AID });
                }
            }

            db.OL.Add(oLevel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = oLevel.AID });
        }
        return View(oLevel);
    }
```

Basically, a user shouldn't be able to add a record where the `PostPreID` equals 2 for a specific date if there is already a record in the database where `PostPreID` is 2 for that specific date.  Same logic goes for when `PostPreID` equals 3.

I have debugged, and entered in both 2 and 3 for `PostPreID` for dates that I know the database doesn't contain those records, but for some reason the nested if statement containing the *.Any* method always resolves to true.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` is correct?  Also, to debug this, call `db.OL.FirstOrDefault` and pass it the same expression to see what record it sees that you aren't expecting.

Comment: Share the source code for the `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`

Comment: @DavidPine It's part of EF https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @David Honestly I am not sure that `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` is correct.  The only reason I am using it is b/c Date is of type `DateTime`  where the time is incorporated but it is not needed for this conditional statement, so I figured `Db.Functions.TruncateTime` would remove the time off of the record and binding property and just compare the dates.. and do you mean: `if (db.OL.FirstOrDefault(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(oLevel.Date) && x.PostPreID == oLevel.PostPreID))`?

Comment: So `TruncateTime` removes the time and just compares the two dates, for example `'4/11/2016 12:48 PM' == '4/11/2016 6:37 AM'` would be true!

Comment: The code in both the `if`s are the same.  Why not combine them `if(oLevel.PostPreID == 2 || oLevel.PostPreID == 3)`?

Comment: @juharr I plan on simplifying my code once I get the issue resolved. I just wanted to write out all blocks first to get it working.. then combine

Comment: I think what David meant was `var firstMatch = db.OL.FirstOrDefault(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(oLevel.Date) && x.PostPreID == oLevel.PostPreID)`  Then change the `if` to `if(firstMatch != null)`.  You can debug as see the the values of `firstMatch`.

Comment: @juharr ok i just did that.. and when I debugged the value it gave me wasn't even for the correct `AID`... so when I initially created.. the initial `oLevel` binded an `AID` of 6.. but when I debugged to the `var firstMatch = db.OL.FirstOrDefault(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(oLevel.Date) && x.PostPreID == oLevel.PostPreID);` the `AID` was 7.. which I don't understand how that happened but I added another condition after `x.PostPreID == oLevel.PostPreID` which was `x.AID == oLevel.AID`.  Thank you

Comment: @David if you want you can post and i will give you credit

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to the `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date)`. So `TruncateTime` removes the time and just compares the two dates, for example:

```
'4/11/2016 12:48 PM' == '4/11/2016 6:37 AM'
```

would evaluate as true. This means that regardless of the times, as long as the dates and the IDs are the same -- the `.Any` will always be true.

Comment: How can that be true if there is more than 1 condition in the `.Any`?  I am saying *if **Any** record in the database has the same `date` **AND** `PostPreID` as what is being binded in the `oLevel` object, then post an error*.  I am not just comparing dates.

Comment: My point is that both conditions are true, it's just that the conditions are not explicit enough. Both the dates (once truncated) and the IDs are the same.

Comment: Ok. Well I added on to my conditional statement `if (db.OL.Any(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(oLevel.Date) && x.PostPreID == oLevel.PostPreID && x.AID == oLevel.AID))` and that worked. guess that's more explicit? :)